# Loop through module and run inspect.getdoc() on each method

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I can print a list of all the builtins:

```
for i, b in __builtins__.__dict__:
    print(i, b)

__name__
__doc__
__package__
__loader__
__spec__
__build_class__
__import__
abs
all
any
ascii
...
```

Then `import inspect` and `inspect.getdoc(<some_module>)`.

First thought was:

```
for b in __builtins__.__dict__:
    print(b, inspect.getdoc(b))
```

But *you know* that at that point "b" is just a string of the name of the module.

Tried: `dir(__builtins__)`, which also seems to be a list of strings.

Using `list` wont work:

```
list(__builtins__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

Obviously, I can just [read the docs online](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), but am wondering if there *is* a way to do what I'm trying to do *within* Python... rather *how* it can be done.

Ultimately, it would be really cool to have a little generator that can output them one by one:

```
mybuiltins.next()
Method: reversed
Doc: 'Return a reverse iterator over the values of the given sequence.'
```

Comment: Does anything stop you from doing something like `for k,v in __builtins__.__dict__.items():print(k, inspect.getdoc(v))`?

Comment: If the key in this dictionary is the name of a module, function or something else, the value is the actual object.

Comment: "But you know that at that point "b" is just a string of the name of the module." - did you try using it as a key in `__builtins__.__dict__` (which you already know to be a dictionary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, using `dict.items`:

```
builtins = {k: inspect.getdoc(v) for k, v in __builtins__.__dict__.items()}
```

Here's some example usage:

```
# Get a specific builtin
builtins['reversed'] # 'Return a reverse iterator over the values of the given sequence.'
getattr(__builtins__, 'reversed') # <class 'reversed'>
```

```
# List all the builtin names, and their doc, as in your example
for k, v in builtins:
    print(k, v)
```